# Countdown timer for songs in android

Tags: android, timer, media-player, seekbar

I'm trying to make a simple music player project with a countdown timer that will countdown the time of songs as they play, but I don't know how to get the song duration into my countdown timer.

I am using a textView. I have seen all of the previous questions posted here and I still don't get it. I have made a countdown timer like this one:

```
   private class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        SongLength.setText(hms);
    }
}
```

and this part too:

```
   final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(220000, 1000);
   timer.start();
```

Now this counts when CounterClass is given some parameters, like in the example above - **but how do I get the song duration?** I have a `seekBar` also, should I use `mediaPlayer` or `seekBar` duration?

Answer (score 0):

You should use getDuration from MediaPlayer class to get the duration of the song http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html.
something like this

```
//initializationcode
mPlayer.getDuration();
```

that duration is given in milliseconds as you can see in the javadoc.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to do that?I don't know how to put the duration of the song in the string or the countdown timer.